# Google Line Charts X-axis Scale on datetime

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, charts, line

Is there an option on Google Charts to set the x-axis scale more thin ?

Here is my Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7z16m379/

If you zoom on the last 3 days, the X-axis do not show the date anymore but only the Hours.
I want to hide the Day only if you choose to display a 24 hour period.

I read the Google Line Charts but do not found any option for that.

Thanks for your help

Nic

```js
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls', 'charteditor']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Month','Temps','r'],
         [new Date(2016,05,12,21,44),599,590],
[new Date(2016,05,13,04,04),578,567],
[new Date(2016,05,13,16,54),2117,1486],
[new Date(2016,05,13,17,05),2022,1122],
[new Date(2016,05,13,17,16),2158,1626],
[new Date(2016,05,13,17,26),2019,1409],
[new Date(2016,05,13,17,47),1642,2249],
[new Date(2016,05,13,17,58),1412,1542],
[new Date(2016,05,13,18,09),1315,1882],
[new Date(2016,05,13,18,20),1389,1570],
[new Date(2016,05,13,18,31),1313,1888],
[new Date(2016,05,13,18,42),1141,1383],
[new Date(2016,05,13,18,53),997,1238],
[new Date(2016,05,13,19,03),969,923],
[new Date(2016,05,13,19,13),866,866],
[new Date(2016,05,13,19,23),804,650],
[new Date(2016,05,13,19,33),628,616],
[new Date(2016,05,13,19,43),620,598],
[new Date(2016,05,13,19,54),630,595],
[new Date(2016,05,13,20,04),611,590],
[new Date(2016,05,13,20,15),614,595],
[new Date(2016,05,13,20,25),597,579],
[new Date(2016,05,13,20,35),617,581],
[new Date(2016,05,13,20,45),591,574],
[new Date(2016,05,13,20,55),597,578],
[new Date(2016,05,13,21,56),622,573],
[new Date(2016,05,13,22,06),577,589],
[new Date(2016,05,13,22,16),604,580],
[new Date(2016,05,14,06,57),604,548],
[new Date(2016,05,14,07,08),576,550],
[new Date(2016,05,14,07,19),578,552],
[new Date(2016,05,14,07,30),592,551],
[new Date(2016,05,14,07,41),579,551],
[new Date(2016,05,14,07,52),582,548],
[new Date(2016,05,14,08,02),581,549],
[new Date(2016,05,14,08,12),596,566],
[new Date(2016,05,14,08,22),583,566],
[new Date(2016,05,14,08,32),586,560],
[new Date(2016,05,14,08,42),590,562],
[new Date(2016,05,14,08,52),598,565],
[new Date(2016,05,14,09,02),596,566],
[new Date(2016,05,14,09,12),602,568],
[new Date(2016,05,14,09,23),595,571],
[new Date(2016,05,14,10,44),634,600],
[new Date(2016,05,14,11,15),634,590],
[new Date(2016,05,14,11,25),657,600],
[new Date(2016,05,14,12,47),632,593],
[new Date(2016,05,14,12,57),620,594],
[new Date(2016,05,14,13,08),617,579],
[new Date(2016,05,14,13,19),617,573],
[new Date(2016,05,14,13,29),628,573],
[new Date(2016,05,14,13,40),618,582],
[new Date(2016,05,14,13,50),626,573],
[new Date(2016,05,14,14,01),645,587],
[new Date(2016,05,14,14,12),631,590],
[new Date(2016,05,14,14,22),640,605],
[new Date(2016,05,14,14,32),655,599],
[new Date(2016,05,14,14,42),640,607],
[new Date(2016,05,14,14,53),637,607],
[new Date(2016,05,14,15,03),634,598],
[new Date(2016,05,14,15,34),637,615],
[new Date(2016,05,14,15,44),613,614],
[new Date(2016,05,14,15,54),643,602],
[new Date(2016,05,14,16,04),641,610],
[new Date(2016,05,14,16,15),616,596],
[new Date(2016,05,14,16,26),637,607],
[new Date(2016,05,14,16,37),615,606],
[new Date(2016,05,14,16,48),612,606],
[new Date(2016,05,14,16,59),624,599],
[new Date(2016,05,14,17,10),630,628],
[new Date(2016,05,14,17,20),621,639],
[new Date(2016,05,14,17,30),631,633],
[new Date(2016,05,14,17,40),622,615],
[new Date(2016,05,14,17,50),613,640],
[new Date(2016,05,14,18,00),618,637],
[new Date(2016,05,14,18,10),612,635],
[new Date(2016,05,14,18,21),621,652],
[new Date(2016,05,14,18,31),623,667],
[new Date(2016,05,14,18,42),616,680],
[new Date(2016,05,14,18,52),621,652],
[new Date(2016,05,14,19,53),619,659],
[new Date(2016,05,14,20,03),603,621],
[new Date(2016,05,14,20,13),607,585],
[new Date(2016,05,14,20,24),619,591],
[new Date(2016,05,15,10,33),613,575],
[new Date(2016,05,15,11,25),618,593],
[new Date(2016,05,16,13,53),602,579],
[new Date(2016,05,16,14,03),615,588],
[new Date(2016,05,16,14,14),626,578],
[new Date(2016,05,16,14,35),618,574],
[new Date(2016,05,16,15,16),603,633],
[new Date(2016,05,16,15,26),614,604],
[new Date(2016,05,16,15,36),618,588],
[new Date(2016,05,16,15,46),605,580],
[new Date(2016,05,16,15,56),616,593],
[new Date(2016,05,16,16,06),621,604],
[new Date(2016,05,16,16,17),619,635],
[new Date(2016,05,16,16,27),608,608],
[new Date(2016,05,16,17,58),630,711],
[new Date(2016,05,16,18,39),617,919],
[new Date(2016,05,16,18,50),614,899],
[new Date(2016,05,16,19,00),616,846],
[new Date(2016,05,16,19,11),610,873],
[new Date(2016,05,16,19,21),602,866],
[new Date(2016,05,16,19,32),615,764],
[new Date(2016,05,17,08,30),1147,1676],
[new Date(2016,05,17,13,39),613,612],
[new Date(2016,05,17,13,49),613,684],
[new Date(2016,05,17,14,00),620,639],
[new Date(2016,05,18,04,31),1141,541],
[new Date(2016,05,18,04,42),1123,531],
[new Date(2016,05,18,11,54),613,597],
[new Date(2016,05,18,12,04),633,590],
[new Date(2016,05,18,12,14),602,592],
[new Date(2016,05,18,12,25),602,586],
[new Date(2016,05,18,12,36),596,597],
[new Date(2016,05,18,12,47),613,579],
[new Date(2016,05,18,13,58),617,577],
[new Date(2016,05,18,14,08),625,597],
[new Date(2016,05,18,14,18),612,591],
[new Date(2016,05,18,14,29),619,596],
[new Date(2016,05,18,14,39),613,602],
[new Date(2016,05,18,14,49),630,599],
[new Date(2016,05,18,14,59),629,592],
[new Date(2016,05,18,15,09),618,600],
[new Date(2016,05,18,15,19),623,599],
[new Date(2016,05,18,15,29),602,607],
[new Date(2016,05,18,15,39),616,625],
[new Date(2016,05,18,15,49),637,616],
[new Date(2016,05,18,15,59),626,609],
[new Date(2016,05,18,16,09),626,605],
[new Date(2016,05,18,16,20),670,643],
[new Date(2016,05,18,16,30),655,644],
[new Date(2016,05,18,16,40),659,675],
[new Date(2016,05,18,16,51),646,716],
[new Date(2016,05,18,17,02),666,795],
[new Date(2016,05,18,17,13),683,959],
[new Date(2016,05,18,17,23),694,901],
[new Date(2016,05,18,17,33),791,986],
[new Date(2016,05,18,17,44),808,995],
[new Date(2016,05,18,17,54),772,1269],
[new Date(2016,05,18,18,04),802,1623],
[new Date(2016,05,18,19,30),615,1075],
[new Date(2016,05,19,14,21),620,593],
[new Date(2016,05,19,14,31),623,609],
[new Date(2016,05,19,14,41),629,600],
[new Date(2016,05,19,14,52),611,600],
[new Date(2016,05,19,15,03),624,597],
[new Date(2016,05,19,18,06),1156,683],
[new Date(2016,05,19,18,16),985,636],
[new Date(2016,05,19,18,26),909,646],
[new Date(2016,05,19,18,37),835,631],
[new Date(2016,05,19,19,28),621,596],
[new Date(2016,05,19,19,38),613,603],
[new Date(2016,05,19,19,49),605,597],
[new Date(2016,05,19,19,59),614,578],
[new Date(2016,05,19,20,10),595,582],
[new Date(2016,05,19,20,21),596,573],
[new Date(2016,05,19,20,32),588,570],
[new Date(2016,05,19,20,43),609,579],
[new Date(2016,05,19,20,54),606,582],
[new Date(2016,05,19,21,05),597,573],
[new Date(2016,05,19,21,16),599,579],
[new Date(2016,05,19,21,27),589,569],
[new Date(2016,05,19,21,38),736,581],
[new Date(2016,05,19,22,39),683,593],
[new Date(2016,05,20,08,07),727,1244],
[new Date(2016,05,20,08,18),744,1477],
[new Date(2016,05,20,08,29),819,1843],
[new Date(2016,05,20,08,40),764,1633],
[new Date(2016,05,20,10,02),620,680],
[new Date(2016,05,20,10,12),616,610],
[new Date(2016,05,20,10,22),626,598],
[new Date(2016,05,20,10,32),621,610],
[new Date(2016,05,20,11,13),604,604],
[new Date(2016,05,20,12,25),617,649],
[new Date(2016,05,20,12,36),616,596],
[new Date(2016,05,20,12,47),603,589],
[new Date(2016,05,20,12,58),626,589],
[new Date(2016,05,20,13,08),626,591],
[new Date(2016,05,20,13,19),619,586],
[new Date(2016,05,20,15,51),645,603],
[new Date(2016,05,20,17,32),1459,817],
[new Date(2016,05,20,18,03),1863,970],
[new Date(2016,05,20,18,14),2064,1084],
[new Date(2016,05,20,18,24),2080,1017],
[new Date(2016,05,20,18,35),2179,775],
[new Date(2016,05,20,18,46),1986,666],
[new Date(2016,05,20,18,57),2364,665],
[new Date(2016,05,20,19,08),1590,628],
[new Date(2016,05,20,19,18),1630,605],
[new Date(2016,05,20,19,29),1124,604],
[new Date(2016,05,20,19,40),840,604],
[new Date(2016,05,20,19,51),850,591],
[new Date(2016,05,20,21,12),588,559],
[new Date(2016,05,20,21,23),587,570],
[new Date(2016,05,20,21,34),583,569],
[new Date(2016,05,21,08,54),602,571],
[new Date(2016,05,21,09,05),588,581],
[new Date(2016,05,21,09,16),609,572],
[new Date(2016,05,21,09,26),613,577],
[new Date(2016,05,21,09,37),612,574],
[new Date(2016,05,21,09,47),609,593],
[new Date(2016,05,21,09,57),604,589],
[new Date(2016,05,21,10,08),612,594],
[new Date(2016,05,21,10,18),636,583],
[new Date(2016,05,21,10,28),610,598],
[new Date(2016,05,21,10,38),615,580],
[new Date(2016,05,21,10,48),644,580],
[new Date(2016,05,21,10,58),632,588],
[new Date(2016,05,21,12,09),610,606],
[new Date(2016,05,21,12,20),618,600],
[new Date(2016,05,21,12,30),623,593],
[new Date(2016,05,21,12,41),658,606],
[new Date(2016,05,21,12,51),642,584],
[new Date(2016,05,21,13,02),1000,584],
[new Date(2016,05,21,17,41),612,773],
[new Date(2016,05,21,17,51),607,738],
[new Date(2016,05,21,18,02),616,735],
[new Date(2016,05,21,18,12),629,736],
[new Date(2016,05,21,18,22),629,780],
[new Date(2016,05,21,18,32),635,814],
[new Date(2016,05,21,19,13),616,925],
[new Date(2016,05,21,20,26),605,604],
[new Date(2016,05,21,20,37),594,591],
[new Date(2016,05,21,20,48),560,584],
[new Date(2016,05,21,20,59),597,559],
[new Date(2016,05,21,22,10),603,579],
[new Date(2016,05,21,22,21),590,581],
[new Date(2016,05,21,22,31),602,602],
[new Date(2016,05,21,22,42),582,588],
[new Date(2016,05,21,22,52),604,586],
[new Date(2016,05,21,23,02),609,567],
[new Date(2016,05,21,23,12),593,573],
[new Date(2016,05,21,23,22),568,603],
[new Date(2016,05,22,09,13),605,561],
[new Date(2016,05,22,09,24),598,553],
[new Date(2016,05,22,09,34),604,587],
[new Date(2016,05,22,09,45),597,558],
[new Date(2016,05,22,09,55),609,569],
[new Date(2016,05,22,10,06),604,570],
[new Date(2016,05,22,10,17),603,587],
[new Date(2016,05,22,10,28),603,581],
[new Date(2016,05,22,10,39),616,579],
[new Date(2016,05,22,10,49),625,581],
[new Date(2016,05,22,11,00),616,580],
[new Date(2016,05,22,11,11),623,591],
[new Date(2016,05,22,11,22),626,602],
[new Date(2016,05,22,11,33),619,582],
[new Date(2016,05,22,11,44),625,585],
[new Date(2016,05,22,11,55),615,580],
[new Date(2016,05,22,12,06),598,582],
[new Date(2016,05,22,12,17),628,584],
[new Date(2016,05,22,12,27),621,572],
[new Date(2016,05,22,12,37),611,565],
[new Date(2016,05,22,12,47),604,559],
[new Date(2016,05,22,12,57),592,575],
[new Date(2016,05,22,13,07),594,592],
[new Date(2016,05,22,13,17),606,575],
[new Date(2016,05,22,13,27),624,573],
[new Date(2016,05,22,13,37),602,586],
[new Date(2016,05,22,13,48),591,587],
[new Date(2016,05,22,13,58),595,571],
[new Date(2016,05,22,14,08),616,582],
[new Date(2016,05,22,14,18),626,582],
[new Date(2016,05,22,14,28),615,579],
[new Date(2016,05,22,14,38),615,574],
[new Date(2016,05,22,14,48),606,584],
[new Date(2016,05,22,14,58),614,575],
[new Date(2016,05,22,15,08),606,577],
[new Date(2016,05,22,15,18),619,578],
[new Date(2016,05,22,16,19),607,581],
[new Date(2016,05,22,16,30),600,583],
[new Date(2016,05,22,21,21),585,575],
[new Date(2016,05,22,22,12),598,588],
[new Date(2016,05,22,22,22),613,591],
[new Date(2016,05,23,08,24),621,1726],
[new Date(2016,05,23,08,35),615,1627],
[new Date(2016,05,23,08,46),640,1439],
[new Date(2016,05,23,09,27),597,1182],
[new Date(2016,05,23,09,38),610,1323],
[new Date(2016,05,23,09,48),618,862],
[new Date(2016,05,23,11,24),591,599],
[new Date(2016,05,23,11,55),607,721],
[new Date(2016,05,23,12,26),599,594],
[new Date(2016,05,23,12,37),606,575],
[new Date(2016,05,23,12,48),589,596],
[new Date(2016,05,23,12,58),588,585],
[new Date(2016,05,23,13,08),583,584],
[new Date(2016,05,23,13,18),590,579],
[new Date(2016,05,23,13,29),603,590],
[new Date(2016,05,23,13,39),614,769],
[new Date(2016,05,23,13,49),603,925],
[new Date(2016,05,23,13,59),617,1090],
[new Date(2016,05,23,14,09),615,790],
[new Date(2016,05,23,14,19),616,610],
[new Date(2016,05,23,14,30),597,634],
[new Date(2016,05,23,15,12),613,607],
[new Date(2016,05,23,15,23),617,604],
[new Date(2016,05,23,15,34),611,589],
[new Date(2016,05,23,15,44),606,600],
[new Date(2016,05,23,15,54),627,608],
[new Date(2016,05,23,16,05),775,598],
[new Date(2016,05,23,16,28),828,606],
[new Date(2016,05,23,16,40),679,727],
[new Date(2016,05,23,16,51),669,932],
[new Date(2016,05,23,17,02),706,1121],
[new Date(2016,05,23,17,10),713,987],
[new Date(2016,05,23,17,20),693,995],
[new Date(2016,05,23,17,30),731,1175],
[new Date(2016,05,23,17,40),716,978],
[new Date(2016,05,23,17,50),669,1089],
[new Date(2016,05,23,18,00),697,1243],
[new Date(2016,05,23,18,10),641,1020],
[new Date(2016,05,23,18,20),633,1216],
[new Date(2016,05,23,18,30),604,901],
[new Date(2016,05,23,18,40),619,774],
[new Date(2016,05,23,18,50),616,723],
[new Date(2016,05,23,19,00),602,671],
[new Date(2016,05,23,19,10),604,608],
[new Date(2016,05,23,19,20),608,595],
[new Date(2016,05,23,19,30),608,592],
[new Date(2016,05,23,19,40),601,581],
[new Date(2016,05,23,19,50),606,574],
[new Date(2016,05,23,20,00),585,574],
[new Date(2016,05,23,20,10),587,579],
[new Date(2016,05,23,20,20),606,610],
[new Date(2016,05,23,20,30),594,573],
[new Date(2016,05,23,20,40),585,571],
[new Date(2016,05,23,20,50),584,574],
[new Date(2016,05,23,21,00),597,571],
[new Date(2016,05,23,21,10),584,572],
[new Date(2016,05,23,21,20),601,575],
[new Date(2016,05,23,21,30),599,594],
[new Date(2016,05,23,21,40),603,627],
[new Date(2016,05,23,21,50),602,642],
[new Date(2016,05,23,22,00),611,638],
[new Date(2016,05,23,22,10),607,650],
[new Date(2016,05,24,10,10),621,587],
[new Date(2016,05,24,10,20),611,588],
[new Date(2016,05,24,10,30),608,590],
[new Date(2016,05,24,10,40),604,605],
[new Date(2016,05,24,10,50),606,599],
[new Date(2016,05,24,11,00),614,604],
[new Date(2016,05,24,11,10),619,592],
[new Date(2016,05,24,11,20),616,590],
[new Date(2016,05,24,11,30),604,584],
[new Date(2016,05,24,11,40),598,588],
[new Date(2016,05,24,11,50),608,595],
[new Date(2016,05,24,12,00),609,602],
[new Date(2016,05,24,12,10),600,595],
[new Date(2016,05,24,12,20),608,575],
[new Date(2016,05,24,12,30),627,600],
[new Date(2016,05,24,12,40),607,604]      ]);
      
      
      
    
    var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

    var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'control_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 0,
            ui: {
                chartOptions: {
                    height: '100',
                    width: '70%',
                    chartArea: {
                        width: '80%'
                    }
                },
                chartView: {
                    columns: [0, 1]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        containerId: 'chart_div'
    });

    function setOptions (wrapper) {
        // sets the options on the chart wrapper so that it draws correctly
        // the chart editor automatically enables animations, which doesn't look right with the ChartRangeFilter
        wrapper.setOption('height', '600');
        wrapper.setOption('width', '70%');
        wrapper.setOption('animation.duration', 0);
    }
    
    setOptions(chart);
       
    
    
    dash.bind([control], [chart]);
    dash.draw(data);
}
  
    </script>





  

<div id="dashboard">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <div id="control_div"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can listen for the `'statechange'` event on the control
and adjust the format according to the `range` values

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month','Temps','r'],
      [new Date(2016,05,12,21,44),599,590],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,04,04),578,567],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,16,54),2117,1486],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,17,05),2022,1122],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,17,16),2158,1626],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,17,26),2019,1409],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,17,47),1642,2249],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,17,58),1412,1542],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,18,09),1315,1882],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,18,20),1389,1570],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,18,31),1313,1888],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,18,42),1141,1383],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,18,53),997,1238],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,19,03),969,923],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,19,13),866,866],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,19,23),804,650],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,19,33),628,616],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,19,43),620,598],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,19,54),630,595],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,20,04),611,590],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,20,15),614,595],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,20,25),597,579],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,20,35),617,581],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,20,45),591,574],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,20,55),597,578],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,21,56),622,573],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,22,06),577,589],
      [new Date(2016,05,13,22,16),604,580],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,06,57),604,548],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,07,08),576,550],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,07,19),578,552],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,07,30),592,551],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,07,41),579,551],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,07,52),582,548],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,08,02),581,549],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,08,12),596,566],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,08,22),583,566],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,08,32),586,560],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,08,42),590,562],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,08,52),598,565],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,09,02),596,566],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,09,12),602,568],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,09,23),595,571],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,10,44),634,600],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,11,15),634,590],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,11,25),657,600],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,12,47),632,593],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,12,57),620,594],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,13,08),617,579],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,13,19),617,573],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,13,29),628,573],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,13,40),618,582],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,13,50),626,573],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,14,01),645,587],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,14,12),631,590],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,14,22),640,605],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,14,32),655,599],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,14,42),640,607],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,14,53),637,607],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,15,03),634,598],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,15,34),637,615],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,15,44),613,614],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,15,54),643,602],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,16,04),641,610],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,16,15),616,596],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,16,26),637,607],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,16,37),615,606],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,16,48),612,606],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,16,59),624,599],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,17,10),630,628],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,17,20),621,639],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,17,30),631,633],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,17,40),622,615],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,17,50),613,640],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,18,00),618,637],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,18,10),612,635],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,18,21),621,652],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,18,31),623,667],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,18,42),616,680],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,18,52),621,652],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,19,53),619,659],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,20,03),603,621],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,20,13),607,585],
      [new Date(2016,05,14,20,24),619,591],
      [new Date(2016,05,15,10,33),613,575],
      [new Date(2016,05,15,11,25),618,593],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,13,53),602,579],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,14,03),615,588],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,14,14),626,578],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,14,35),618,574],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,15,16),603,633],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,15,26),614,604],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,15,36),618,588],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,15,46),605,580],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,15,56),616,593],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,16,06),621,604],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,16,17),619,635],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,16,27),608,608],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,17,58),630,711],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,18,39),617,919],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,18,50),614,899],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,19,00),616,846],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,19,11),610,873],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,19,21),602,866],
      [new Date(2016,05,16,19,32),615,764],
      [new Date(2016,05,17,08,30),1147,1676],
      [new Date(2016,05,17,13,39),613,612],
      [new Date(2016,05,17,13,49),613,684],
      [new Date(2016,05,17,14,00),620,639],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,04,31),1141,541],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,04,42),1123,531],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,11,54),613,597],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,12,04),633,590],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,12,14),602,592],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,12,25),602,586],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,12,36),596,597],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,12,47),613,579],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,13,58),617,577],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,14,08),625,597],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,14,18),612,591],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,14,29),619,596],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,14,39),613,602],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,14,49),630,599],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,14,59),629,592],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,15,09),618,600],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,15,19),623,599],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,15,29),602,607],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,15,39),616,625],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,15,49),637,616],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,15,59),626,609],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,16,09),626,605],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,16,20),670,643],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,16,30),655,644],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,16,40),659,675],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,16,51),646,716],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,17,02),666,795],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,17,13),683,959],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,17,23),694,901],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,17,33),791,986],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,17,44),808,995],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,17,54),772,1269],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,18,04),802,1623],
      [new Date(2016,05,18,19,30),615,1075],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,14,21),620,593],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,14,31),623,609],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,14,41),629,600],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,14,52),611,600],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,15,03),624,597],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,18,06),1156,683],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,18,16),985,636],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,18,26),909,646],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,18,37),835,631],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,19,28),621,596],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,19,38),613,603],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,19,49),605,597],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,19,59),614,578],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,20,10),595,582],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,20,21),596,573],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,20,32),588,570],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,20,43),609,579],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,20,54),606,582],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,21,05),597,573],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,21,16),599,579],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,21,27),589,569],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,21,38),736,581],
      [new Date(2016,05,19,22,39),683,593],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,08,07),727,1244],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,08,18),744,1477],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,08,29),819,1843],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,08,40),764,1633],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,10,02),620,680],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,10,12),616,610],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,10,22),626,598],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,10,32),621,610],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,11,13),604,604],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,12,25),617,649],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,12,36),616,596],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,12,47),603,589],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,12,58),626,589],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,13,08),626,591],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,13,19),619,586],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,15,51),645,603],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,17,32),1459,817],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,18,03),1863,970],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,18,14),2064,1084],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,18,24),2080,1017],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,18,35),2179,775],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,18,46),1986,666],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,18,57),2364,665],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,19,08),1590,628],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,19,18),1630,605],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,19,29),1124,604],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,19,40),840,604],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,19,51),850,591],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,21,12),588,559],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,21,23),587,570],
      [new Date(2016,05,20,21,34),583,569],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,08,54),602,571],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,09,05),588,581],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,09,16),609,572],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,09,26),613,577],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,09,37),612,574],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,09,47),609,593],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,09,57),604,589],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,10,08),612,594],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,10,18),636,583],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,10,28),610,598],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,10,38),615,580],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,10,48),644,580],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,10,58),632,588],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,12,09),610,606],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,12,20),618,600],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,12,30),623,593],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,12,41),658,606],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,12,51),642,584],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,13,02),1000,584],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,17,41),612,773],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,17,51),607,738],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,18,02),616,735],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,18,12),629,736],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,18,22),629,780],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,18,32),635,814],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,19,13),616,925],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,20,26),605,604],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,20,37),594,591],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,20,48),560,584],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,20,59),597,559],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,22,10),603,579],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,22,21),590,581],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,22,31),602,602],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,22,42),582,588],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,22,52),604,586],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,23,02),609,567],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,23,12),593,573],
      [new Date(2016,05,21,23,22),568,603],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,09,13),605,561],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,09,24),598,553],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,09,34),604,587],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,09,45),597,558],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,09,55),609,569],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,10,06),604,570],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,10,17),603,587],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,10,28),603,581],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,10,39),616,579],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,10,49),625,581],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,11,00),616,580],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,11,11),623,591],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,11,22),626,602],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,11,33),619,582],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,11,44),625,585],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,11,55),615,580],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,12,06),598,582],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,12,17),628,584],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,12,27),621,572],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,12,37),611,565],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,12,47),604,559],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,12,57),592,575],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,13,07),594,592],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,13,17),606,575],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,13,27),624,573],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,13,37),602,586],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,13,48),591,587],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,13,58),595,571],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,14,08),616,582],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,14,18),626,582],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,14,28),615,579],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,14,38),615,574],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,14,48),606,584],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,14,58),614,575],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,15,08),606,577],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,15,18),619,578],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,16,19),607,581],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,16,30),600,583],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,21,21),585,575],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,22,12),598,588],
      [new Date(2016,05,22,22,22),613,591],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,08,24),621,1726],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,08,35),615,1627],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,08,46),640,1439],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,09,27),597,1182],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,09,38),610,1323],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,09,48),618,862],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,11,24),591,599],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,11,55),607,721],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,12,26),599,594],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,12,37),606,575],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,12,48),589,596],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,12,58),588,585],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,13,08),583,584],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,13,18),590,579],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,13,29),603,590],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,13,39),614,769],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,13,49),603,925],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,13,59),617,1090],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,14,09),615,790],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,14,19),616,610],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,14,30),597,634],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,15,12),613,607],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,15,23),617,604],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,15,34),611,589],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,15,44),606,600],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,15,54),627,608],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,16,05),775,598],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,16,28),828,606],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,16,40),679,727],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,16,51),669,932],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,17,02),706,1121],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,17,10),713,987],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,17,20),693,995],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,17,30),731,1175],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,17,40),716,978],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,17,50),669,1089],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,18,00),697,1243],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,18,10),641,1020],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,18,20),633,1216],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,18,30),604,901],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,18,40),619,774],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,18,50),616,723],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,19,00),602,671],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,19,10),604,608],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,19,20),608,595],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,19,30),608,592],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,19,40),601,581],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,19,50),606,574],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,20,00),585,574],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,20,10),587,579],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,20,20),606,610],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,20,30),594,573],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,20,40),585,571],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,20,50),584,574],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,21,00),597,571],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,21,10),584,572],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,21,20),601,575],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,21,30),599,594],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,21,40),603,627],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,21,50),602,642],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,22,00),611,638],
      [new Date(2016,05,23,22,10),607,650],
      [new Date(2016,05,24,10,10),621,587],
      [new Date(2016,05,24,10,20),611,588],
      [new Date(2016,05,24,10,30),608,590],
      [new Date(2016,05,24,10,40),604,605],
      [new Date(2016,05,24,10,50),606,599],
      [new Date(2016,05,24,11,00),614,604],
      [new Date(2016,05,24,11,10),619,592],
      [new Date(2016,05,24,11,20),616,590],
      [new Date(2016,05,24,11,30),604,584],
      [new Date(2016,05,24,11,40),598,588],
      [new Date(2016,05,24,11,50),608,595],
      [new Date(2016,05,24,12,00),609,602],
      [new Date(2016,05,24,12,10),600,595],
      [new Date(2016,05,24,12,20),608,575],
      [new Date(2016,05,24,12,30),627,600],
      [new Date(2016,05,24,12,40),607,604]
    ]);

    var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

    var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
      containerId: 'control_div',
      options: {
        filterColumnIndex: 0,
        ui: {
          chartOptions: {
            height: '100',
            width: '70%',
            chartArea: {
              width: '80%'
            }
          },
          chartView: {
            columns: [0, 1]
          }
        }
      }
    });

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'LineChart',
      containerId: 'chart_div'
    });

    google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'statechange', function () {
      var dateRange = control.getState().range;
      var dayInMS =  1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
      var periodShown = dateRange.end.getTime() - dateRange.start.getTime();
      if (periodShown <= dayInMS) {
        chart.setOption('hAxis.format', 'H:MM:SS');
      } else {
        chart.setOption('hAxis.format', 'MM/dd/yyyy');
      }
      chart.draw();
    });

    function setOptions(wrapper) {
      wrapper.setOption('height', '600');
      wrapper.setOption('width', '70%');
      wrapper.setOption('animation.duration', 0);
      wrapper.setOption('hAxis.format', 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    }

    setOptions(chart);

    dash.bind([control], [chart]);
    dash.draw(data);
  },
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
  <div id="control_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not exactly what i want to do.

The option you give is to set the x axis format.

I want the format dynamically change using the control bar below. If i display 24 hour data i need to see the hour, if i want to display more than 1 day i need to see the date.

Thanks for your help

Comment: not sure to understand the last answer.  "based on the control values, see edit... " ??? how could i change it ?

Comment: i changed the answer, to use the control `range` values -- now when the range displays 24 hours or less, the `hAxis.format` will change -- see the `'statechange'` event

Comment: Wonderfull !!! Many Thanks, just one thing it's "        chart.setOption('hAxis.format', 'H:mm:ss');" MM are for month and SS micro second